# broadcast to have application launch count

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcast, launch

How can I get the launch count of all applications? I have the complete list of installed apps, and I have a broadcast when an application is installed, but I need the launch count of any apps.
I see this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.bstatspro&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnJvb3R1bmluc3RhbGxlci5ic3RhdHNwcm8iXQ..) with this. You have the cpu time, the foreground time, and the launch count... how do they do it??

Answer (score 3):

Finally i do that! i create a AlarmManager that every minute check the running applications, if an application in running (background or active) i check the last time that i saw it. if this time is greater than one minute i increase the count.
Now i'm trying to have how many data the application sent to an external server, i have this data, but do you know if this data is from i have installed my application or from when i boot my smartphone?

```
 Long txByte = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(listApp.getAppsRunning().get(i).getPid());
```

this code is for get the count time

```
for(int i=0; i< listApp.getAppsRunning().size(); i++)
    {
        String pName = listApp.getAppsRunning().get(i).getPackageName();
        String Ldate = "0";
        int Nrun = 0;
        Long Ntime = null, Ndata = null ;
        Cursor c=db.fetchInstalled(pName);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            Nrun =  c.getInt(2);
            Ldate = c.getString(3);
            Ntime = c.getLong(4);
            Ndata = c.getLong(5);


            Log.d("db", "last time: " + Nrun+ " time: " + Ldate);
        }

        if(Ldate.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        {
            Nrun++;
            db.updateLaunchAndTime(Nrun, lastUpdated, pName, Ntime, Ndata);
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy h:mmaa"); 
            Date lastDate = null;
            Date currentDate = null;
            try {
                lastDate = dateFormat.parse(Ldate);
                currentDate = dateFormat.parse(lastUpdated);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //int pid = android.os.Process.getUidForName(listApp.getAppsRunning().get(i).getPid());
            Long txByte = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(listApp.getAppsRunning().get(i).getPid());
            Log.d("pid process", "pid: " + listApp.getAppsRunning().get(i).getPid());

            Ndata = txByte;

            Log.d("data send", "send: " + Ndata);

            long diff =  currentDate.getTime() - lastDate.getTime();
            if(diff > 100* 1000)
            {
                Log.d("db", "difference plus 1 min app: " + pName);
                Nrun++;
            }
            Ntime = Ntime+diff;


            db.updateLaunchAndTime(Nrun, lastUpdated, pName, Ntime, Ndata);
        }
        //db.insertRunningP(pName   , lastUpdated);
    }
    db.close()
```

I checked the power consume of this code and is less than 3% of total battery, so for now this is the best solution that i have found

Comment: its very bad way to do that, cause it will drain battery, there should be some better way to do this.

Comment: @AndreaC If i use a application for 2 hours what will be launch count according your answer

Answer (score 2):

I've never done it before, but I'm pretty sure http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html provides the information you need.

Comment: With the activitymanager you Cannot have the launched time.. Probably With the battery stats you Can have... Do you have any idea if its possibile ho have a broadcast messagge when the user Lunch An application? 
Thanks

Comment: I don't see anyway to do that.

Comment: it's impossible, this app have the statiscs https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.bstatspro&hl=it

Answer (score 1):

if you had rooted your device, you also can read the usage stats files in `/data/system/usagestats/usage-*` for detail infomation.